# Sum with chebyshev function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I want to compute the value of the following sum:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\psi(2n+1)}{2n}-\frac{\psi(2n)}{2n}$$

$\psi$ is the second Chebyshev function. It is defined in Mathematica as:

$$\psi(x) = \sum_{p \le x} \lfloor \log_p x\rfloor \log p$$

The sum is absolutely convergent because: $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\psi(x)}{x}=1$$.